# PHP: file_put_contents() strips last tab (\t)

Tags: php, tabs, fopen, strip, file-put-contents

I wrote a webservice which allows (after authentication of course) to transfer file contents via post, which gets written into a file. Everything works fine, unless the last char(s) are a tab or a tab followed by a linebreak, which both get stripped. This causes serious problems with csv files, separated by a tab.

A I don't know the file contents in advance, I cannot just manually add a tab at the end.

Multipart/form-data for a file upload is not possible, as the other client doesn't support it.

`fopen` + `fwritwe` produce exactly the same issue.. Any ways around this?

Comment: Can you post you code? I try to reproduce your problem, but i can't. This example of code work fine. `file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', "hello world\t");`

Answer (score 0):

use the trim() function to trim the leading and tailing spaces. For tail space use rtrim(), you also can specify the char you want to drop.

```
file_put_contents($filepath, rtrim("with tab\t", "\t"));
```